# Python executing file which is inside usr/local and not from the main directory?

Tags: python, linux

I am working with a python tool called Pyggi and when I execute a py file, lets say `"hello_world.py"` which has a function inside it called `"print_hello_world()"`.
`"print_hello_world()"` resides in another folder within the tool's files. example folder structure is given below

`pyggi

> example
> > hello.world.py
> utils
> > utils.py`

I noticed that any changes in `utils.py` was not reflecting. I later found out that there is another copy of pyggi tool in my `usr/local/lib/python3.10` and my tool was using its `utils.py`
When I made changes to `utils.py` inside `python3.10` folder I could see the changes.

Why is my tool executing a file which is in python3.10 folder?
How can I fix this?

Initially I had an environment setup and the same copy of pyggi tool was inside my environment as well and utils.py was being used by it. So, when I removed my environment I found out that `usr/local/lib/python3.10` also has copy and now `usr/local/lib/python3.10` was being used.